# Method 'range' failed. VBA

Tags: excel, vba, methods, range

```
Sub tester()

Dim total As Integer
Dim z As Integer

For z = 4 To 90

    If Not IsNull(Range("c" & z)) Then
        total = total + Application.WorksheetFunction.Index(Range("h2:h69171"), Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(Cells("c" & z) & Cells("A98").Value, Range("l2:l69171"), 1))
    End If

Next z

Range("b98").Value = total

End Sub
```

This code is giving me a "Method 'Range' of object'_Global' failed"  (on the If... line).  Can someone please help me to figure out why?  Thanks in advance

Comment: As you write it, the `Range` applies to the active sheet. If none are active, you get an error. Try to specify for which sheet you want the range, something along the lines of `Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("C" & CStr(z))`. Of course, you should replace `"Sheet2"` with the name of your sheet.

Comment: Review "total". That's where your problem is. You probably don't need to use Index(Match()) either. There are plenty of other, better ways to find something using VBA.

Comment: Thanks.  unfortunatly this code gives the same error. :(

If Not IsNull(Worksheets("Inter").Range("C" & CStr(z))) Then

Comment: Better ways as in a loop?  Is that faster?

Comment: Read through this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839746(v=office.15).aspx Your problem may also not be with total. I read through your question a little quickly and misunderstood. I'm still trying to duplicate the error.

Comment: 1) Match() is not a member of WorksheetFunction. It is a member of Application, so your code should be Application.Match('other stuff') 2) It would be helpful to understand hat kind of information you are working with and exactly what you're trying to do. Working with some simple ranges and numbers, I can't get the IF Not IsNull(Range("c" & z)) then to fail. The only time I can get errors is with something inside the if statement.

Comment: If you're using Excel 2003, you're running into row limitations.

Comment: You're also misusing Cells(). Cells has an argument for a row number and column number. It will not accept a range address like "A1". This will cause an invalid procedure call error in your "total =" line though, not the error you describe. Instead of 'If Not IsNull(Range("c" & z)) Then' try 'If cells(z, "c")<>"" Then'

Comment: Thanks for all the help.  I am really not use to VBA as you can see.  I want to go through a list that is anywhere between 1 and 86 rows and add that to 1 cells data for every row.  Then I want to look up that new value in a table and output a corresponding value for all the totals in the list

Comment: @asp8811 Why do you write that?  Documentation in both HELP and MSDN shows Match as being a method of the WorksheetFunction object.  WorksheetFunction, in turn, is a property of the Application object.  Match can used either as Worksheetfunction.Match OR as Application.Match.  The difference between the two has to do with error handling.

Comment: @Ron Rosenfeld When I used Application.WorksheetFunction.Match trying to replicate the error in the OP, I got an error that Match was not a member of WorksheetFunction. I was pretty sure it should be, but I know that some worksheet functions do not exist under WorksheetFunction. That's the only reason.

Answer (score 2):

```
Sub tester()

    Dim total As Integer
    Dim z As Integer
    Dim wf As WorksheetFunction

    Set wf = Application.WorksheetFunction

    With Sheet1

        For z = 4 To 90
            If Not IsEmpty(.Cells(z, 3).Value) Then
                total = total + wf.Index(.Range("h2:h69171"), wf.Match(.Cells(z, 3).Value & .Cells(98, 1).Value, .Range("L2:L69171"), 1), 1)
            End If

        Next z

        .Range("b98").Value = total
    End With

End Sub
```

Cells takes a row and column argument. And it's good to prefix all your range references with a sheet - I use a With Block and start the range references with a period to accomplish that.

Also, when you don't supply a column argument to INDEX, it returns the whole row.

I created a wf variable simply to keep the code brief and readable.